# Why does [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO] crash my app?

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7

Same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480796/uiappearance-settranslucent-error-illegal-property-type-c-for-appearance-sette), but that question was shunned (because of NDA at the time) and is no longer active.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:'
```

I'm setting this in `viewDidLoad` of my initial view controller. `setTranslucent` comes up on autocomplete, and does not complain until crashing and talking about swizzles and things.

Any info on this would be great, I'm still having a very rough time getting a consistent status bar appearance across my app.

Comment: Are you running in the iOS 7 simulator or an iOS 7 device? If not, the `setTranslucent` property won't exist and thus cause the crash.

Comment: It crashes on simulator or device?

Comment: You said it crashes right? I don't quite understand your response.

Comment: I was testing on the simulator, and I wasn't sure which (device or simulator) you meant did not have the translucent property. But I assume now you mean simulator. So now I must ask- why does the simulator's library not have `translucent`?

Comment: Disregard my comment from earlier. I was misunderstanding. Check my answer.

Comment: This happens for "[UITabBar appearance].translucent" in iOS7 too.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It seems that the `translucent` property just can't be set using `UIAppearance`. I don't know exactly why, but I guess some properties just aren't supported. However, I solved this by creating a custom `UIViewController` and making all other viewControllers in my app a subclass of that custom viewController. That way, I can set global properties (such as `translucent` in your case) that will be inherited by all other viewControllers in my app. I know that's kind of a big change, but I hope it helps.

**** **EDIT** ****

As of iOS 8, translucency can be set with UIAppearance:

Objective C

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];
}
```

Swift

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 8.0 {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
}
```

Comment: I ended up just setting the translucency in each view controller manually. Quicker, but not as clean as subclassing or defining a protocol.

Comment: iOS 8 started supporting setting translucency via UIAppearance.

Comment: While the explanation makes sense, the conformsToProtocol check also passes for iOS 7. Ended up with a system version check before setting the translucent property.

Comment: As @e_x_p says, it's better to check if respond to selector, so you will void that future versions breaks and it will work always when it is available.

 if([[UINavigationBar appearance] respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)])

Comment: replace now with UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true

Answer (score 8):

You can fool it though by specifying a non exist image, which will amke the tool bar go opaque

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:219.0/255.0 green:67.0/255.0 blue:67.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your question and I got here from google but if you use navigation controllers, I can change all the translucency with this line:

```
[self.navController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

you crash because you use the illegal method.
in `UIAppearance` , it says

```
To participate in the appearance proxy API, tag your appearance property selectors in your header with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.
```

it means when you use `[[XXX appearance] method]`,the method method must have the attribute UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR,or it may throw an exception,and `translucent` does not have it.

but what puzzles me is that, `[[XXX appearance] method]` in iOS8 it's ok but crashes in iOS7 and apple document does not say it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change translucent property after class has been initialized.

```
[newsViewNavigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

I did something like this and it worked!