# Changing navigation items color through the entire app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to change the tint Color of the back button in iOS 7. Now Is there a way to change all navigation items throughout the entire app to a specific color? This is what i have in one view controller as of right now:

```
self.editButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.title = @"Inbox";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
```

Comment: I've answer a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18934411#18934411

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`UINavigationItem` is not a view and it doesn't have a color.

You instead want to change the `UIBarButtonItem` tint color.

Using the `UIAppearance` proxy you can do

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This will change the `tintColor` of each `UIBarButtonItem` in the application.

You can use the same strategy to change the `UINavigationBar` `barTintColor` and `titleTextAttributes`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // this will change the back button tint
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Unfortunately [there's no way of changing the `translucent` property using the proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480796/uiappearance-settranslucent-error-illegal-property-type-c-for-appearance-sette), so you will have to do it on each bar.

Comment: Awesomeness, that's basically what I was asking, but this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, and remember that this is only iOS 7 compatible.

Comment: Hmm.. well it changed the tint of the items except for <HOME button. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean the back button? Try setting also the `tintColor` property

Comment: I tried this, but it won't work:  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Comment: It changed from back to home because I set a title for the previous page.

Comment: try changing the `tintColor` property of the navigation bar.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella But how do you set this for the whole app, I dont see that part of the answer?

Comment: @meda that's the very essence of the appearance proxy. By working on `[UINavigationBar appearance]` you are setting properties for every instance of `UINavigationBar` further allocated.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella oh ok I get it now, proxy terminology confused me thanks :)

Comment: Gabriele you mentioned further (future or still to be created presumed) allocated. I think this is exactly my problem, I want to change the color of an existing already created UIBarButtonItem (s). This is done dynamically after the application has launched.

Any ideas on how to change existing already create item tint color?

Answer (score 4):

Swift answer

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
```

put it in your AppDelegate's  func application(application: UIApplication,     `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS7 you can set a tintcolor for all the navigation items just to keep a consistent look and feel all over the app:

```
 if ([self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
        self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Also look at my answer here for recommended reading and viewing material:
[StatusBar bug in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574293/statusbar-bug-in-ios7/19575040?noredirect=1#comment29054398_19575040)

Comment: I think the user is asking about `UINavigationBar` and `UIBarButtonItem`, your answer applies for more than he asks.

Answer (score 0):

In the `superViewDidLoad` method.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

it would change the color of navigation item's color.
And same will happen with button.

Comment: The question was about entire app.

Answer (score 0):

This works for changing the back button color:

```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Tested with iOS 9.3, iPhone and iPad. Your navigationBar title will still be colorized with the default color. It was is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For Title Label Color, we can use

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```